# CSGO Floating in the Air when Spawn

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Sometimes when I spawn I float in to air. It has happened several times. Does anyone know why this bug happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why it happens, nor can I tell you how the engine works (because I don't work at Valve).

You can easily fix this by hitting Jump or Crouch.